# How to add different values to matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix

To add different values to every row in a matrix is very simple by using the recycling:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, ncol=4)
print(m + c(100, 200, 300))
```

But how can I add a different value to every column? For example, to get the following result:

```
101 204 307 410
102 205 308 411
103 206 309 412
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing with the transpose:

```
t(t(m) + c(100,200,300,400))
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  101  204  307  410
[2,]  102  205  308  411
[3,]  103  206  309  412
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine I'll finish typing this before someone ninjas me, but:

method one:

```
for (j in 1:4) m[,j]<-m[,j]+100*j
```

method two:

```
addmat<-  matrix(rep(1:4,each=4),nr=4)*100
m + addmat
```

Answer (score 1):

If the vector containing the different values has a length egual or multiple to the number of column of `m` you can do this

```
> mapply(`+`, as.data.frame(m),c(100, 200, 300, 400))
      V1  V2  V3  V4
[1,] 101 204 307 410
[2,] 102 205 308 411
[3,] 103 206 309 412
```